# A can do a job in three hours, B can do it in 4. How long does it take them together?

Tags: average, word-problem

As it says in the question： if one person can do a job in 4 hours, and another can do the job in 3 hours, how quickly can they do the job together in they can work together?

My attempt was this: Average them together, $\frac{3+4}{2}=3.5$, then say that these workers take an average of 3.5 hours to do the job, together, they should be able to do it half of their average time, $\frac{7}{4}$ hours, which is one hour 45 minutes.

The answer is apparently 1 hour and 15 minutes.  Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I agree with your answer. Maybe it's a typo.

Comment: Using the harmonic mean, I get $\approx$ 1 hour 42.86 minutes.

Comment: The answer of 1 hour 15 minutes can't be right. If you had two workers who could each do one job in 2.5 hours, then working together they could achieve that time, but both A and B work more slowly than that.

Comment: Depending on the job, A and B start arguing and never finish. If the job is "carry a letter from X to Y" then they take four hours together, three hours if A does the job alone. If the job is carrying a heavy weight that a person alone almost cannot move, but two can lift it, they might take 10 minutes doing it together.

Answer (score 4):

A's power is $P_A=\frac{W_A}{t_A}$, where $W_A$ is the "work" produced by A in time $t_A$. So, if A finishes $1$ piece of work in $4$ hours, then his power is 
$$P_A=\frac{1}{4}$$
B's power is $P_B=\frac{W_B}{t_B}=\frac{1}{3}$. When A and B work simultaneously their powers add to produce the total power:
$$P_{AB}=P_{A}+P_{B}\Leftrightarrow\frac{W_{AB}}{t_{AB}}=\frac{W_A}{t_A}+\frac{W_B}{t_B}\Leftrightarrow\frac{1}{t_{AB}}=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{3}$$
Now you just have to solve the last equation for $t_{AB}$.

Comment: the only assumption is that during the simultaneous operation of A and B the power of each one of them is not affected by the power of the other.

Comment: ..But how should I have known, without using this, that my original answer was wrong sir?

Comment: Since A needs $3$ hours and B needs $4$ hours to complete the job, an obvious remark is that working together they will be faster than the fastest among the two. So they will definitely need less than $3$ hours. Averaging the two times produces  a number between $3$ and $4$ which is absurd.

Answer (score 1):

A does 0.33333 job/h

B does 0.25 job/h

Together 0.58333 job/h

Reciprocal is 1.7143 (ie. 12/7) h/job

Comment: Of course you have to assume that this is the sort of job where output is proportional to time, where A and B can work independently and you can combine their outputs to get the total.  This wouldn't work in more complicated situations, e.g. if you have to wait a certain time for the first coat of paint to dry before applying the second.